# Can you have two or more .wine installs or wine .desktops?

Tags: 20.04, wine, cinnamon, mint, winetricks

I would like to run an app twice or more. It is to host a game server for an old car game.

Example is:

```
wine desktop 1 = game server with sports cars mod
wine desktop 2 = game server with 1967 cars mod
wine desktop 3 = game server with 1955 cars mod 

etc etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The magic word is Wineprefixes, see here:
https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Wineprefixes

There's also a GUI solution called playonlinux (name is misleading, it's not only for games). You can use it to manage wineprefixes, wine versions, create launchers etc.